# Modeling the dissolution of an oil droplet with detergent

Tags: physical-chemistry

- How to model the dissolution of an oil droplet on the surface of water when a detergent is (gradually) added to the water?

I believe this includes an interplay of coalescence keeping the droplet together and dissolution tearing it apart. Adding the detergent then changes the system so that the dissolution becomes stronger.

So far I tried a partial differential equation approach with the Cahn–Hilliard equation. However this model seems not to account for the coalescence, so that the droplet is always dissolved regardless of the parameters.

[image: oil droplet]